# fill in a table with some words letters

Tags: string-manipulation, list-manipulation

I have a list of words

```
list={"ingenuous", "forgotten", "tree", "supercomput", "hundred"}
```

How can I put the letters of each word in an element of a table such as here:

[image]

Comment: You misspelled "ingenious". In any event: have you seen `Characters[]`?

Comment: Better answers are given, but here is quick one:  `TableForm[Characters /@ list, TableHeadings -> {list, None}]` .

Comment: @AntonAntonov Note that `TableForm` cannot set gridding line. :)

Comment: @yode I know, that is why I said there are better solutions... Also, I think `TableForm` is under-appreciated, that is why I provided a line with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {"ingenious", "forgotten", "tree", "supercomput", "hundred"};
list /. word_String :> Join[{word}, Characters@word] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image: table]

Comment: This is a winning answer I think. :)

Comment: If one is not deterred by `/.`, `:>`,`@`, `//`, `#&` and friends this style of writing mathematica code is imho the most readable of all.

Comment: I'd have done `Prepend[Characters[word], word]` myself.

Comment: Another possibility is using `{word} ~Join~ Characters@word`. Sometimes (not necessarily in this case) infix notation helps to further convey what the particular line of code does (precedence becomes somewhat difficult to assess though)

Answer (score 2):

As the promp of [Sascha's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120257/21532),I simplify this code be

```
list={"ingenuous","forgotten","tree","supercomput","hundred"};
Grid[Join[List/@list,Characters/@list,2],Frame->All,Spacings->{2.6,0.5}]
```

[image]